# jQuery: How do i trigger event / do something when select option is selected?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone let me know the best way to trigger an event once a select option has been clicked on and chosen?

I want to run some additional JavaScript once the user has selected their option.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`$.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // Additional JavaScript
});
```

To get the value of the option chosen, use `$(this).val()` within the scope of the function, like this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

---

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you can use it with `$.on()` as with any other event:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    // Additional JavaScript
});
```

Comment: I'd go with the on() approach

Comment: @Shenaniganz I would too, however the OP or future visitors might be stuck with a version less than 1.7.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#my-select').change(function(){ 
  //do stuff here, eg. 
  if ($(this).val() == 'xyz') { //check the selected option etc.
     //do more stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: There is no need for the complicated selector - `$(this).val()` does the same thing.